# How to integrate COM API(C++) to C#?

Tags: c#, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have referred the following article link. It explains about custom properties and custom events for UI Automation.

Here is the link:
[Registering the custom properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
. But i don't know how to implement this. Can anyone provide proper steps to implement this?

Because the implementation provided in the article link is about C++ implementation. that's why i can't able to understand how to integrate that code in C#

**Sample Code which is provided in the MSDN link**

```
// Create the registrar object and get the IUIAutomationRegistrar 
// interface pointer. 
IUIAutomationRegistrar * pUIARegistrar = NULL;
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomationRegistrar, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IUIAutomationRegistrar, (void **)&pUIARegistrar);

if (pUIARegistrar == NULL)
    return E_NOINTERFACE;

// Register the property and retrieve the property ID. 
HRESULT hr = pUIARegistrar->RegisterProperty(&MyCustomPropertyInfo, &g_MyCustomPropertyID);
pUIARegistrar->Release();

return hr;
```

How to embed COM API to C# as it needs that implementation?

Comment: I just asked about how to implement this. Because the implementation provided in the article link is about C++ implementation. that's i cannot able to understand how to integrate that code in C#....Did you referred that article?

Comment: I have implemented coded ui like this way provided in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369291/exposing-custom-properties-using-ui-automation-framework
After further googled, i have found that MSDN link to provide custom properties.

Comment: It usually is already done for you when you use C#.  If you use Winforms then you have the AccessibleDescription/Name/Role properties for a control.  If you use WPF then you have the System.Windows.Automation namespace beyond its built-in support for exposing Content.  That namespace contains the managed version of the C++ api you found.

Comment: I am using Windows forms. Is there any way to show the custom properties?